# Nginx reverse proxy to Apache2 - not working - too many redirects

Tags: apache, nginx, server, debian, reverse-proxy

at the beginning, I want to apologize, but I am a newbie with Nginx.

I have a VPS where I have some PHP/Symfony projects (hosted in Apache2). Now I need to add a new application (in Vue especially NuxtJS) to the VPS.

So I decided to setup Nginx with reverse proxy to Apache2. My idea was that on Nginx could run the NuxtJS app and the PHP apps could still be on Apache2.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server

- Firstly I changed `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file. Listen 80 to Listen 8080 and remove 443 SSL options. In this file is only `Listen 8080` now.
- Then I changed configs in `/etc/apache/sites-available`. I edited my existing configs for PHP projects as:

1. remove SSL configs
2. edit `www.domain.com.conf` and `domain.com.conf` -> rewrite *80 to *8080
3. sudo a2dissite on domains in apache2

- Next I installed Nginx, uncomment gzip options in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add `proxy_cache_path /var/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=reverse_cache:60m inactive=90m max_size=1000m;`
- After that, I removed a `default` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and created an `apache` file in the same directory.
- Linked an apache file with `ln -s apache /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.
- Reject direct access to Apache using `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 ! -s your_server_ip -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`

Nginx config file `Apache` looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name my_domain.cz www.my_domain.cz;
    root /var/www/my_domain/web;
    index index.php app.php index.htm index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }   

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.cz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.cz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    server_name adminer.my_domain.cz www.adminer.my_domain.cz;
    root /var/www/adminer;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/adminer.my_domain.cz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/adminer.my_domain.cz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

In `proxy_pass` option I tried `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or my public IP of the server.
No one of these options works.

Nginx running (`sudo nginx -t` is OK), Apache2 too.
When I am trying to access my website I got `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
I am desperate. None of the advice that I found worked.

Comment: `nginx` conf seems fine, please add apache conf

Comment: Did you try HTTP or HTTPS URL. I dont see HTTP server block here. If thats already added check with single website first. If thats working check the second one alone.

Comment: Did you fix this already?

Comment: Yes and no. I uninstalled Apache2 and started to use only Nginx for all my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error basically means that you have a redirection loop. Since you are reconfiguring your server there can be several causes of the loop. First, just make sure to delete all cookies and cache in your browser and also, if any, caches on the server.

If that is not solving the loop, it might be caused by a redirect to https in a `.htaccess` or apache config file on your apache php server.

Most servers these days are configured to redirect all traffic from http to https. In the `.htaccess` file you might find something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Basically, this means that all requests which are not https, will be redirected to https.

Since you have reconfigured the apache server to http and all requests from the Nginx reverse proxy will be http, the server will send a redirect request (301) to the browser. The browser will send a https request to Nginx, which forwards it as a http request to Apache, which sends a redirect to https to the browser. This will be an infinite loop. The browser recognizes this loop and will throw the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Deleting the redirect to https in a `.htaccess` or the apache virtual host config may solve your problem.

Comment: The OP didn't mention the presence of .htaccess, although it's a good advice to check it

Comment: Yes, this rule I had in the .htaccess file. So is possible that this was the problem. However I solved this problem with uninstalling Apache2 and started to use Nginx for all my projects.

Comment: Great you solved it. In the long run, you even might be better of only having to maintain only one tool for same the purpose instead of two.